# Cannot Ping Server Despite UFW Inactive, Server Can Ping Other Devices

Tags: networking, server, firewall, ufw, ping

I'm running Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 LTS on a computer on my home network, connected via wifi. It can connect to the internet, and can ping other devices like my main Windows PC and my phone just fine, however whenever I try to ping the server from my PC, the requests just timeout.

UFW is disabled on the server so the pings shouldn't be blocked. I've also tried it after enabling file and printer sharing on my main PC, and I even disabled Windows Defender, just in case the responses were being blocked for some reason.

I've checked at least a dozen times using `ip a` and `ifconfig`, and I'm confident the IP of the server is correct, I'm not using `docker0`, `eno1`, or `lo`, but rather `wlp1s0`, the wifi network adapter that gives a valid IP.

I'm at a loss for what the issue could be, so any help would be really appreciated.

Edit: SSH also times out, and Zenmap/Nmap traceroute shows that it is up, but doesn't give any further info.

Comment: I think you have "wi-fi" isolations in your router...check it and update us

Comment: While that wasn't the issue, your answer did get me thinking about the router side more. As it would turn out, my place has two different routers, and my PC and server were connected to different ones lmao. My PC has a wired connection that runs through walls, while my server was connected via WiFi, so while dumb, it wasn't an obvious error to spot, at least at my knowledge level. So thanks since it did help anyway haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, my place has two different routers, and my PC and server were connected to different ones. My PC has a wired connection that runs through walls, while my server was connected via WiFi, so while dumb, it wasn't an obvious error to spot, but was fixed easily.